# C# Grabbing Input Text and pushing to an integer

Tags: c#, textfield

I am trying to get this piece of code working in C#, what I want to do is if a textfield is updated to validate its an integer (HP is an integer).

So by attempting to convert the input to an integer, I either get a new integer, and sets the value to it, or if it fails, it takes the previous verified value and pushes back to the text field (pretty much ignoring the input, updating it, and it is now a validated input).

In my head this is all logic and working, in effect its not. Please help.

```
private void Input_HP_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Try
    {
        HP = Convert.ToInt32(Input_HP.Text);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Input_HP.Text = HP;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use try.parse, but you will want to set it to a temporary variable.  In your case, using HP will overwrite your variable you want to save.

```
int tempInt;
if(Int32.TryParse(Input_HP.Text, out tempint))
{
    HP = tempInt;
}
else
{
    Input_HP.Text = HP.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks worked like a charm (had to make sure tempInt were used all over, and to close the If with a ")" ;)

Answer (score 3):

Int.TryParse is probably what you are looking for:

```
int HP;
if (int.TryParse(Input_HP.Text, out HP))
{
  // the number is an integer at this point
}
```

Comment: This will set the text value to "0" if it fails the validation, instead of the stored HP variable.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. Plus @TomGarske has made the valid point that you could end up overwriting the value of HP to zero and therefore losing the original value which is required in order to revert the invalid input

Comment: Thanks for the input with the TryParse, that was the function I were looking for, later answers had the effect I wanted to ensure the value got kept.

Comment: Fair point all. Taoh, accept the answer below if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

If HP is an integer you cannot directly assign it to the `Text` property because this is of type `String`. This should be a compile time error, for this part of the code you should be using the `.ToString()` function...

```
Input_HP.Text = HP.ToString();
```

Of course, you should be using a `TryParse` for this conversion anyway. I guess what you want is something like this...

```
private void Input_HP_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 0;
    if(int.TryParse(Input_HP.Text, out i))
    {
       HP = i;
    }
    else
    {
       Input_HP.Text = i.ToString();
    }
}
```